# Can I convert string to memoryview?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets, udp, memoryview

So I have 2 programs which I am connecting via UDP.

Sender:

```
self.v = memoryview(self.Data)
sock.sendto(self.v, (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
```

Receiver:

```
self.rcv, self.addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
```

You can notice that what I am passing is a `memoryview` object and this is what I would like to receive. But it doesn't work that way. What I receive is a `string` which I'd like to convert back to `memoryview`. Is it possible?

self.Data is a bytearray

Comment: Did you try calling `memoryview` on it?

Comment: What do you mean? Like `x = memoryview(self.rcv)` ?

Comment: Yes, like that.

Comment: Why are you using ``memoryview``? Especially in the Sender. You can feed ``self.Data`` directly to ``sendto``.

Comment: Sockets send and receive *bytes*. It seems you already know how to convert a string to a `memoryview` object, so I'm not really sure what you are asking...

Comment: @IrmendeJong I agree, it seems entirely unnecessary.